# How to tell if Gatsby Image component has loaded?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

I have a `GatsbyImage` / `StaticImage` component and I use the `onLoad` event to trigger an animation. But once the browser has cached the image, the `onLoad` event never fires again. So if you visit a different page and then return, the animation isn't triggered.

The usual workaround with an ordinary image would be to attach a `ref` and then check `ref.current.complete` to see if the image had loaded. But `GatsbyImage` refuses to take a ref.

So

1. Is there any way to add a ref to the `GatsbyImage` component?
2. Is there any other way to detect if the image has loaded?
3. Is the only alternative to use an ordinary `img` tag (and lose out on all the gatsby image magic)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is there any way to add a ref to the GatsbyImage component?

Apparently, you can't. According to this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/30937) it throws the following exception:

> Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref
> will fail. Did you mean to use `React.forwardRef()`?

That said, you can try using `forwardRef()` which will give you a valid scope for your use-case.

> 2. Is there any other way to detect if the image has loaded?

Not directly. However, you can try the [`onStartLoad` callback](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-image/#gatsby-image-props) which expose the `wasCached` boolean that gives your more information and control about the browser cache. You can play around with that boolean to trigger the animation again or to use the value globally along with a `useState` for example:

```
<GatsbyImage
  fadeIn={false}
  className="customImg"
  onLoad={() => {
    // do loading stuff
  }}
  onStartLoad={({ wasCached }) => {
    // do stuff on start of loading
    // optionally with the wasCached boolean parameter
  }}
  onError={(error) => {
    // do error stuff
  }}
/>
```

> 3. Is the only alternative to use an ordinary `img` tag (and lose out on all the gatsby image magic)?

You can find a bunch of dependencies to lazy-load, fade, blur, get background primary color, etc of an image but its implementation, behavior, and compatibility will rely on the library itself. So, yes, there are alternatives but I'm not sure if they are worth it.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! For anyone else reading this, I never managed to attach a ref, not even with `forwardRef()`, but using the `onStartLoad` callback worked perfectly.